# Go oauth2 package: err is always nil?

Tags: go, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to pass the error down from my handler to my route function, although its always nil?

Registered my password authorization handler:

```
oauthServer.SetPasswordAuthorizationHandler(func(username, password string) (userID string, err error) {
    var user User

    var queryError = database.Model(User{}).
        Where("email = ?", username).
        First(&user).
        Error

    if errors2.Is(queryError, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
        return "", errors2.New("No Email")
    }

    if bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(user.Password), []byte(password)) == nil {
        return string(user.ID), err
    }

    return "", errors2.New("Incorrect Password")
})
```

Route:

```
myRouter.HandleFunc("/token", handleTokenRequest).Methods("GET")
```

handleTokenRequest:

```
func handleTokenRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := oauthServer.HandleTokenRequest(w, r)
    if err != nil { // always nil
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to know why `oauthServer.HandleTokenRequest` always returns `nil` you should include `oauthServer.HandleTokenRequest` in the question. For all we know the `oauthServer.SetPasswordAuthorizationHandler` may be completely unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @mkopriva this is not my code, its part of the popular oauth2 package. https://github.com/golang/oauth2

Comment: There is no `HandleTokenRequest` in that repository as far as I can tell. https://github.com/golang/oauth2/search?q=HandleTokenRequest

Comment: @mkopriva https://github.com/go-oauth2/oauth2/blob/master/server/server.go#L496

Comment: If it's not documented you can try asking the authors of that package, under what circumstances the function does or doesn't return an error. Keep in mind that that's not the same package as the one you initially linked.